# Tracking files changes in Java

Tags: java, file, ant, copy, tracking

I have java application. Every time when I'm doing changes in JSP file I need to copy saved JSP to another place (specific project). May be you know tool that can track changes in real time in files in specific folder and after every saving - copy these files to another folder, thanks.

Comment: you have repositories for that when you checkin your files which save both the old changes and versions. why do you want to do it in ur code

Comment: ammm... not exactly. For example I have local project that located an disc C:\, but my sever root folder is locating on disc D:\, so every time when I clicking Ctrl+S I want tool that will copy saved files from C to D.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What if you just saved the file with errors? Set up a proper testing environment (pretty simple with the IDEs available) and use a proper deployment regime.

Comment: oh ok. but if you want to do it from java i guess you will have to do lots of coding. before saving the current file check the last timestamp and compare it with current one and then call a perl script from java to save the old copy and later update ur new copy. seems a lot of work to me. but i guess u can find something in ANT. Well i would not agree with this design may be a last resort and beware of multiple threads accessing the same file.

Comment: so ok, the case that I wrote - it's just simplest way what I need to do, in real case we have a big project with CMS, IDE Eclipse, Ant code testing and stuff like that. I just need to add this little functionality for my reasons =)

Comment: Ok, I found took like Koala - it doing what I need! But it works only with sass/less etc. I need the same just without compilation - only copying =)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse, IntelliJIdea like IDEs have a feature called Local History. you can view, compare replace each saved version through that by few clicks.

In java there is a support for watching file changes. You can use this to implement your own program that listen to file changes and save the version automatically whereever you want.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: but i guess the OP has a different problem. he does not want to use repositories or any eclipse tools for his req :)

Comment: So thats why he has given the url for java watcher API. he can have is own implementation and run that notification service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).  These tools take a little customization, but once configured they make deploying a new version of your application as simple as a single command.  Of course there is a learning curve for both Ant and Maven, so the larger and more complex the project, the more useful and time-saving these resources become.

If you really want the "quick and dirty" option for testing purposes, simply set up a Shortcut located in your Server root folder and pointing to the .jsp file in your development workspace.  Give the shortcut the same name (and relative location) as the original and the shortcut will always mirror your development copy.  Note that I do **not** recommend this option, and am only including it for completeness.